# Is there an alternative library to html5ever that takes a string and returns a queryable object?

Tags: html, rust

I am trying to parse HTML in Rust. The one library that seems to do this is `html5ever`. I can't find any simple way to make it take a string and return a queryable object.

Is there an alternative library that I can use that takes a string and returns an object that I can query on?

I am trying to do something like web scraping here.

I am a complete Rust newbie.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [main function](https://github.com/servo/html5ever/blob/master/examples/print-rcdom.rs#L67) of the official example?

Comment: @michas I didn't see that till now. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [select](https://crates.io/crates/select) crate, which is basically a wrapper over the html5ever, but gives a nicer api.

For example:

```
use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::Name;

for i in Document::from_str(html_src_string).find(Name("article")).iter() {
    println!("{:?}",i.text() );       //prints text content of all articles
};
```

[select.rs](https://github.com/utkarshkukreti/select.rs) repository has more elaborate examples.

Comment: This works for 0.2.2 as of 01/25/2017. But newer versions the API has changed I think.